# JavaScript Objects are shown only the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, css, html, easeljs

I am creating a game with HTML5 and for this I am using the framework easeljs.
The compiler shows no errors and I am able to play the game but not all the objects (images) are shown on the stage. The images are all loaded to the stage but they are only shown if I refresh the page once. Also, images that are shown are not positioned like I programmed them to be positioned. They get the programmed position after I refresh the page once.
For you to know I am using a stage updater like this:

```
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", this.updateStage.bind(this));
```

If you have any idea what the problem is please let me know.

Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: If you are able to provide a link to your source / game (I am not sure if you're comfortable with that), that could definitely help us discover a solution faster.

Comment: Sorry but I can not do that, it is a project for a company, not may own.
Thanky you for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out how to get every image on the stage.
I did not used a preloader to first preload the images and than add them to the stage.
After creating a preloader with PreloadJS everything worked fine.